# What is different between HIR (Hold Items Record) and DIR (Deferred Items Record)?

Tags: faa-regulations, regulations, easa-regulations

I wonder what is exactly different between HIR and DIR?
What is different between HIR (Hold Items Record) and DIR (Deferred Items Record)?